# how to connect reCAPTCHA with a feedback form

Tags: recaptcha

there! My English isn't so good, if you want to clarify smth feel free to ask.
I don't know JS and PHP, but I'm familiar with C#. I need to connect reCAPTCHA to the site.
I've added reCAPTCHA, but I need to connect it with a feedback form. Now reCAPTCHA works itself.

I'm trying to make a callback by watching video on YT, but I don't have a token.
Here's a code of a form:

```
        <div class="form__right">
            <form action="/back-call/send_order.php" method="post" class="fb-form">
                <div class="fb-form__block">
                    <input name="userName" required="" type="text" class="fb-form__input" placeholder="your name" />
                    <input name="userTel" required="" type="tel" class="fb-form__input" placeholder="phone number" />
                    <input name="userText" required="" type="text" class="fb-form__input comments" placeholder="commentary" />
                    <input required="" type="submit" value="submit your application" class="fb-form__input fb-form__input--submit" />
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="fb-form__block flex-c">
          <p style="margin:0; color:#f57f17;">this field is necessary to complete</p>
        </div> -->
                <div class="fb-form__block flex-c">
                    <input checked="checked" required="" type="checkbox" id="iagree2" class="fb-form__checkbox" />
                    <label for="iagree2" class="fb-form__label">I accept the terms <a href="/user-agreement" target="_blank">of the user agreement</a></label>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="divRecaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykey">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```

this is a module on Joomla. I'm editing index php to edit head:

```
<!-- recaptcha-->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
    async defer>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('divRecaptcha', {
          'sitekey' : 'mykey',
          callback: successCallback(),
        });
        function successCallback(token){
here is debbuger to see a token, but it says: undefined.
    }
      };
</script>
```